# Request size limit TileSetSource POST

Tags: mapbox

I am trying to create a TileSet source using the MTS (Mapbox Tiling Service) api. I am uploading a geojson of size 66MB. And it comes back with the error

```
https://api.mapbox.com/tilesets/v1/sources/username/TilesetSourceName?access_token=token
```

```
{
    "message": "request entity too large"
}
```

Api [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/mapbox-tiling-service/#create-a-tileset-source) says each individual source file must not exceed 20 GB.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content-Type was incorrectly set. I was using Postman, latest update seems to have broken it.
It was working fine before. Tried with curl and it worked